# Use of transformer in arc welding

Tags: transformerless

Why transformer is used in arc welding and what will happen when anyone touch the electrode at the time of welding?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_welding#Power_supplies

Answer (score 2):

Modern welders usually don't use mains frequency transformers, rather they are sophisticated IGBT or MOSFET-based converters from mains to DC or synthesized AC (AC is required for welding aluminum, DC is used for steel).

When mains frequency transformer were used (and simulated with modern inverter type power supplies) there are really two types- more-or-less constant voltage (CV) and more-or-less constant current (CC) type. The latter is achieved by the use of magnetic shunts in the transformer. CC is used for TIG (Tungsten Inert Gas) and stick welding. CV is used for MIG flux core welding.

The purpose of the transformer (or switching supply) is to create the CC condition for TIG, to reduce the voltage and increase the current, and to provide some galvanic isolation from the mains, and for big ones, to convert 3-phase input to the required output.

As far as what would happen if you touch the torch- the voltages used for the arc are usually well under 100V, so it's not particularly dangerous, however most TIG welders have a HF (High Frequency) start circuit that generates some thousands of volts at some mA to get the arc going (the ones without HF are called scratch start). It would not be pleasant to touch that. In the old days this was done with a spark gap, kind of a Tesla coil in the welder, inductively coupled to the torch welding cable.

If you're welding you're going to have leather gloves and have the work properly grounded, so it's not so common to get a shock from the HF but it happens.

Comment: You get shocked by HV if you forget to connect ground to the parts being welded, after several events you learn to do that :)

Comment: There are several manufactures that still have mains  frequency transformers based machines, some with thyristor in secondary to some control of the parameters. CV and CC are just use-names for the step or more linear slope of voltage drop vs load. Some GMAW (MIG/MAG) uses CC for aluminum welding for example.

Answer (score 0):

See wikipedia reference by Vladimir [Arc welding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_welding#Power_supplies) , and also [Wikipedia - welding power supply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welding_power_supply)  but a few relevant points :

These points are most applicable to welders with iron cored mains transformers - which is probably what you have in mind. They apply to some extent to high frequency electronically controlled welders but the control circuits and switching power supply modify some characteristics.

- A transformer is used to reduce voltage and increase current. Welding generally uses currents that are higher than can be reasonably supplied by AC mains circuits and the required arc voltage is low once the arc is struck so the gain in available current is a very major factor.
- Arc welding voltages are usually under 50V - classified as ELV = Extra low voltage. The risk of shock is low but not zero. Compared to mains voltages ELV is MUCH safer.
- The required voltage versus load characteristics require a variable impedance supply to allow maximum current control. The transformer supplies this by manipulation of its magnetic circuit.